# Strange alignment of the DuckDuckGo button on the search tips page

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, search

This is a rather minor issue, but in Firefox 10.0 on Windows XP, the **DuckDuckGo** button in the [search tips](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search) is not properly aligned with the **Google** and **Bing** buttons.

[image: Screenshot]

Is this a bug or [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)?

Comment: Your buttons are bigger than anticipated, apparently. Possibly a font issue [like this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109450/150235), but they do [line up on Windows 7, Chrome 18](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mASHp.png).

Comment: Duck? Go? Never saw any such thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're using WinXP and FireFox 10.0?

Here's what I see on Win7 and FireFox 10.0:
[image]

Regardless, we'll increase the width of that box.

Comment: Yes, you're right; this is an issue with Firefox 10.0 on Windows XP.

Comment: This will go out in the next build.